# Does adding a twitter feed from the CEO increase conversion rate of a website?

Tags: profile, conversion-rate, trust

I'm thinking of adding a live twitter feed from the CEO to the company profile page.

Do you know of any research about adding this to an e-commerce site?

I'm asking as twitter is most commonly used by CEO's (probably because it it easy to use and does not take too much time which they do not have to spare) according to this [Google Webmaters video about SEO for startups](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=El3IZFGERbM).

Now it is true that adding a feed by itself is not a cure-all, but in my opinion it may end up adding credibility to a site if visitors can get a short glance into the mind of it's CEO.

You would rather buy from someone you know something about that a total stranger right?

Here's another [case study that compares what generates more trust in customers - twitter or a rare badge](http://visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/split-testing-blog/increase-conversion-rate-with-trust-badges/).

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking us to do a Google search for you. Have you done any research, or searches for anything like this already? What did you find out?

Comment: Would _you_ buy something from a website because the CEO of the company had a twitter feed on it? I wouldn't...

Comment: I am not talking about ONLY having a Twitter feed, but having a Twitter feed in addition to any relevant company info. I've also updated my question.

Comment: I think JonW and Ben got that point.

Comment: It depends on what the CEO has to say. If it's the same old fluff, I'd personally probably *avoid* making a purchase there.

Answer (score 4):

If the CEO is someone I can relate to, think is funny or important figure who make substantial contributions to help organizations, then yes.

- If the CEO is a family member or a friend, then yes, but she would probably not be friend or family member to the majority of others.
- If the CEO is funny, like [Conan O'Brian or Will Ferrel](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/funny-twitter-accounts/).
- If the CEO acts like Bill and Melissa Gates.

But it's unlikely your CEO match any of these criterias on your target audience, so the answer is no. A twitter feed doesn't do more then drawing attention away from what you want your users to do at the site: convert and engage in a purchase or a download. If you have the space, use it for a "popular item list" or "others who bought this also bought list".